# Oracle rebuild- what exactly did our DBA do?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, rebuild

We've had an Oracle 11g database in our business for about 12 months now, and one of our reports was taking 40 minutes to run. Our DBA suggested that we do an unload/reload of all the data.

Now, we were skeptical at first and thought this sounded like a drastic approach, but it has reduced the report time to 3 minutes!!

What exactly did he do here? His description was 
`Data unload/reload is just exporting all the schema objects, dropping the schema (or recrating the database) and importing again.`

It obviously worked what he did, but I am quite amazed Oracle couldn't do this itself. I thought you can rebuild indexs etc without having to do such a thing?

Comment: how does the application load it's data?

Comment: reset HWM? perhaps a lot of DML with insert appends?  Did you ask your DBA why?

Comment: You can rebuild indexes and move tables, but exporting and importing does it all at once.  (Personally I'd rather build a simple PL/SQL script to iterate over the objects, than use something like expdp and impdp, which can be buggy.)  Depending on exactly how you insert and modify your data, there are some weird cases where Oracle will not automatically reclaim empty space in indexes and tables.  But those are exceptions, and you should try to find out exactly why this method worked.  Next time, try comparing DBA_SEGMENTS.BYTES before and after the data reload, to find the relevant objects.

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar problem in one of our Databases. A MERGE statement on a table used to take a long time. When we checked the table size, it was around 900MB. The records in the table were being deleted periodically. After rebuilding the table, the size of the table reduced below 100 MB and the statement execution time increased considerably.

Seems like this works similar to how Disk Defragmentation works.